# What is the difference between praxis and poiesis?

Tags: ethics, aristotle

I have found online this distinction, but I cannot wrap my mind around it:

> **poiesis** - means 'to make'; it is an action that transforms; it refers
>   to 'bringing-forth'; a threshold occasion: a moment of ecstasis when
>   something/s becomes another
>
> **praxis** - a practice (as distinguished from theory); application of
>   skill; conduct in a public space considered as excellence

Can you give some examples?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome, s. dragos.

## Praxis and poiesis

Aristotle's praxis/ poiesis does not mark a single, fixed distinction. The terms bear different senses in different works. But a quite important distinction is one Aristotle draws between praxis (action) in ethics and poiesis (production) in the crafts.

In Aristotle's 'virtue ethics', actions are intentional and voluntary broadly speaking and a morally good action is an intentional, voluntary action done for its own sake and not with a view to a further end. So, for example, a morally good action would be one in which I returned a $50 bill to you simply because you had dropped it and were entitled to be re-possessed of your property: and not because you are good-looking and I reckon my chances for a date. The morally good action is done for its own sake and not for some end separate from it.

Poiesis, now, is different : the activity of practising a craft is an example of poeisis. Intentional, voluntary actions are involved but also, crucially, so is an end-product. In poeisis I am not doing an action or series of actions for its own sake; I aim to produce something - a pot, a vase, a box, a statue - as the end-product. These are quite separate from the actions that produced it.

(T. Irwin, Aristotle: Nicomachean Ethics, 2nd ed, Hackett, 1999: 315 (sense (3) of 'praxis'; and 344 ('produce, production, do, poeisis'.

## Problems with the distinction

JL Ackrill is useful on this point. Consider the following:

> (a) Aristotle holds that when we choose to do something we always
>    choose with a view to some end, for the sake of something; but he
>    also insists that a man who does a virtuous act is not doing it virtuously - is not displaying virtue - unless he has chosen it 'for itself'.
>    (b) Actions are done for the sake of other things, and things we can do
>    are not themselves the ends with a view to which we do them; yet
>    action (praxis) differs from production (poiesis), according to Aristotle,
>    precisely because it is its own end.
>    (c) In recommending the theoretical life Aristotle says that whereas
>    contemplation 'aims at no end beyond itself' fine actions do 'aim at
>    some end and are not desirable for their own sake'; but in recom-
>    mending the life of action he says that doing noble and good deeds
>    is a thing desirable for its own sake, and that 'those activities are
>    desirable in themselves from which nothing is sought beyond the
>    activity'.
>
> Passages like these suggest two problems. First, how can action be good
>    in itself if it is valued as a means to eudaimonia? Secondly, how can an
>    action be something done to bring about an outcome and yet be distinguished from a production because done for its own sake? The first
>    problem invites discussion of Aristotle's view of morality and its foundation: is it valuable in itself or only because it promotes something else?
>    The second-with which the present note is concerned-calls for an
>    examination of Aristotle's concept of an action, and of his distinction
>    between praxis and poiesis.
>
> **Commentators discussing this distinction often fail to face the real
>    difficulty, that actions often or always are productions and productions
>    often or always are actions. (The idea that some periods of the day are
>    occupied by action-episodes and others by production-episodes would
>    obviously be absurd even if 'production' referred only to the exercise
>    of special techniques or skills, since a period of such exercise could
>    certainly be a period during which an action, of promise-keeping for
>    example, was being performed. In fact however Aristotle's notion of
>    production is not limited either to technical performances or to the
>    making of material objects.) The brave man's action is fighting uphill
>    to relieve the garrison, and the just man is paying off his debt by mending
>    his neighbour's fence. How then is one to understand the thesis that
>    paying off a debt is an action but mending a fence is a production?** (JL Ackrill, 'Aristotle on Action',  Mind, New Series, Vol. 87, No. 348 (Oct., 1978), pp. 595-601: 595-6.)

The response to Ackrill is by no means straightforward but this extract may give you an idea of the difficulties which beset Aristotle and his distinctions.

Answer (score 2):

See [*NE*, VI.4, 1140a17-on](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Aristot.+Nic.+Eth.+1140a&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.01.0054) :

> Among things that can be otherwise are included both things made and things done; making [production, *poiesis*] and acting [*praxis*] are different. [...] Making and acting being different, art must be a matter of making, not of acting.

See O.Balaban, [Praxis and Poesis in Aristotle's practical philosophy (1990)](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00149432)

> In ancient-Greek consciousness a valuable activity was that which was undertaken for its own sake and therefore without concern for the amount of time employed in its performance; whereas an action taken as a means to an end was regarded as immoral. In modern society, on the other hand, utilitarian values tend to make it almost [...] The Greeks valued *praxis* more than *poesis*, whereas our culture values *poesis* and *techne* more than *praxis*.

And see also John Ackrill, Aristotle on Action, Mind (1978) :

> Actions are done for the sake of other things, and things we can do are not themselves the ends with a view to which we do them; yet action (*praxis*) differs from production (*poiesis*), according to Aristotle, precisely because it is its own end.